# как на пайтон сделать скришот с курсором мыши

Tags: python, screenshots

не могу найти библиотек которая делает скриншоты с курсором мыши на экране

Comment: Это виндовая проблема с незахватом курсора мыши при скриншоте. Просто пишите в питоне на линуксе! И библиотек никаких не надо. )))

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что существует библиотека с подобным функционалом.

Решение может быть таким:

- Сделать скриншот и захватить позицию указателя мыши PyAutoGui
- Обработать полученный скриншот наложением указателя по захваченным координатам